# Docplex, large number of iterations ( ItCnt = 1.25e+08)

Tags: python, cplex, mixed-integer-programming, docplex

When running the cplex model "docplex(python)", I noticed that the CPLEX repeats the same gap value several times (more than 300 times). without any improvement and with a large number of nodes left to explore (even if the problem is not big enough, number of nodes : 50, number of variables: 8655, number of constraints: 16950). I m asking if it's a normal results and if there are parameters that can help the solver direct the search, like changing the search space without stopping the solver?
(Attached, you can see the log output) [1]: https://www.mediafire.com/file/s9sofxhze8em31y/log_output_2.pdf/file

Comment: This is not uncommon. ["Practical guidelines for solving difficult mixed integer linear programs" !PDF!](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mohamed-Mourad-Lafifi/post/How_to_retrieve_explored_node_and_the_number_of_added_user_defined_valid_cut_when_solving_mip_problem_with_solver_Gurobi/attachment/5ff5a1bad6d0290001a2e52d/AS%3A976944980033538%401609933242569/download/Practical+Guidelines+for+Solving+Difficult+Mixed+Integer+Linear+Programs.pdf) should provide more than enough details.

Answer (score 0):

sascha is correct: there are small MIP problems which are well known to be very hard to solve.
The paper is a good reference.
Additional suggestions: set read datacheck parameter to 2 to rule out potential numerical issues
Try non-standard mip emphasis values, 3 may give good results if best bound is stuck, and 4 sometimes gives very good results. MIP emphasis 5 may help if you set a time limit as it tries to compute good solutions early.

docplex code:

```
mdl.parameters.read.datacheck =2
mdl.parameters.emphasis.mip = 3 (or 4, 5)
```

If this does not work, please publish a larger extract of the CPLEX log, starting a the very beginning.

Comment: There is a small improvement compared to the first result but the gap is still converging slowly. I updated the log file in the post.

Comment: the link in the original post shows a "file deleted" message

Comment: Sorry, I changed the link, plz check again

Answer (score 0):

From the full log, I can see many warnings of this type from the modeling assistant (read.datacheck=2)

```
CPLEX Warning  1008: Detected righthand side <= CPX_MINBOUND at constraint 'c9198'.
```

This means that the constraint's right-hand side is too small. CPLEX comducts all calculartions in floating-point numbers, which are by essence non-exact; therefore all calculations are subject to tolerances.
The tolerance for constraint satisfaction is 1e-6, in other terms a constraint such as

X + 2 Y >= 3

can be satisfied by a CPLEX solution with a tolerance marging of 1e-6

To put it simply: do not use coefficients or constants below 1e-6 (in absolute value) .
Using such tiny values can only perturbate cplex in useless numerical issues.
Either use plain 0 or remove the constraint.
For example, a constraint like:

```
  X + 2 Y <= 1e-12
```

should be written

```
  X + 2 Y <= 0
```

Same rule for coefficients: avoid coefficients below 1e-7. If your data contains them, either filter them out or scale the data.
The recommendation is that in the whole model, the orders of magnitude for coefficients should not span more than 1e+6 , in other terms, the ratio of the biggest to the smallest should stay under 1e+7; otherwise numerical trouble is to be expected.

As for parameters, I see you are using strong branching. Use it only if it really helps as it can be extremely expensive in CPU.
I also noticed you restrained threads to 2, why not let cplex use as many as possible?

To summarize, first fix those tiny coefficients, then try without strong branching and full threads

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, I did what you recommended, it converges too much in the start but then it becomes slow. it is still running from yesterday.  I updated the log file

Answer (score 0):

From your new log, I see all data issues have been fixed, which is good. Still, the mip search is stuck, with best bound not moving.
Your problem has mostly binary variables, so highly combinatorial; such problems can be very hard to solve.
Still, a few general suggestions:

- Try without the mip strategy nodeselect 0, I'm really not convinced this actually helps.
- same for mip strategy file: try removing it
- As your best bound is stuck, did you try with mip emphasis=3, supposed to work on this best bound

In addition you might try the "polishing" heuristic, it sometimes gives good result. To switch to polishing after a given gap value use "set mip strategy polishafter mipgap 0.40" in cplex interactive, this will switch polishing when the 40% gap threshold is passed.

If nothing works, then maybe there are issues in the model formulation itself. One idea is to set a trivial objective (say some variable, or sum of binaries) and see whther the situation improves.
If yes, the issue is in finding better solution, if no, the issue is in finding feasible solutions. IN the latter case, the feasibility pump (mip strategy fpheur 1 or 2) might help.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation very helpful but nothing works in my case, I get a new warning type CPLEX Warning  1036: Decimal part of coefficient for variable 'x_9_18_0' in objective looks like 67/85 in single precision. how to deal with it. another question I want to add a callback function to apply a heuristic after obtaining the same gap value 100 times. how I can call the RINS heuristic. and I want to know if there is a method to change the cuts applied by the solver.

Comment: Warning 1063 is harmless, you can ignore it. RINS heuristic is triggered by parameter `mip.strategy.rinsheur` with a node frequency. Same for cust: all controlled via settings in the `mip.cuts` group: 0 for automatic, 1 for aggressive, 2 for very aggressive

Comment: About mixing callbacks and heuristics, I'm not sure you can set parameters in a cb, never tried.